# Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: expresso-store, paypal, paypal-express-checkout, payment-gateway

I am trying to set up my paypal account for express checkout. It's asking me for the Third Party Permission username. What do I type in for that?

Comment: Please proof read your question before posting :) Also a bit more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're in the wrong place in the Paypal settings. There is no "third party permission username".

Take a look at the [instructions to set up Paypal Express with Store](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/payment_gateways.html#paypal-express-checkout):

> PayPal Express Checkout requires an API Username, Password, and Signature. These are different from your PayPal account details. You can obtain your API details by logging in to your PayPal account, and clicking Profile > My Selling Tools > API Access > Request/View API Credentials > Request API Signature.

Comment: Yeah, I clicked on grant permission by mistake. This is what happens when your kids are asking you questions while reading.

Comment: No problem :) Remember to mark the answer as "accepted" (tick button on the left) once you have a solution.